# AsyncTask on post execute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have 2 fragments:
    **fragment A** and **fragment B**.

In **fragment A** an Async task is executed when user clicks on card view:

Below is the respective code:

```
card1 = (CardView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cardviewone);
         card1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
           card1.setClickable(false);
          new myAsyncTask(chkprog) {
             @Override
             public void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
             a.setText(R.string.string1);
          }
     }.execute();
   }
});
```

How to cancel the on post execute call back in **fragment A** , in case user switched to **fragment B** and prevent app from crashing?

Comment: Does the app crash now ? And do post the code of both the AsyncTask s

Comment: I want a simple condition to add in the onPostExecute , Ex: if layout = layout or fragment = fragment execute code , else do nothing

Comment: post ur crash log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check in your fragment if fragment is visible to user before callback.

Something like this

```
@Override
public void onPostExecute (Void aVoid){
    if (FragmentA.this.isVisible()) {
        a.setText(R.string.string1);
    }
}
```

Comment: View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, container, false); card1 = (CardView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.card1); is it possible to detect if view is visible instead of fragment?

Comment: view will be visible, it has different lifecycle. did the above help?

Comment: public class Fragmenta extends Fragment {
 ...
 
 if (Fragmenta.isVisible())  <-- no static method is visible() cannot be referenced from a static context
{

}
 
}

Comment: I didn't know how to use it.

Comment: In my case : FragmentA.this.isMenuVisible() worked also